# How to hook into wordpress admin upload iframe?

Tags: uploads, thickbox, iframe

I have written a plugin which lets the user upload file attachments for using WordPress as a download site.

So I have added a meta box which shows the user the files he has uploaded for every post. Everything is working fine until I wanted to make it so that if a user uploads file using the built-in upload manager and then closes the ThickBox a function of mine is invoked to update that meta box for new files.

In simple words, I want to be able to listen on the ThickBox close event. That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the thickbox gets closed it triggers 'tb_unload' (in earlier WordPress version it was just 'unload' (not sure though) )

So you can do something like:

```
 $(window).bind('tb_unload', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```